# How can I use the Command Prompt to find the following metadata of files: Authors, Last save by, Owner, Creator?

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, metadata, wmic

I am able to extract metadata using the following prompt:
`wmic datafile where name="Q:\\filename.docx" list full`

And I can see who owns the file or folder using this prompt:
`dir øa  /q`

But I would like to extract the information listed when I right click on a file and got to Properties>Details>Origin, like the file's **Authors, Last save by, Owner, Creator**.

Any idea how I can do this for all the files in a folder, rather than manually execute one file at a time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a great powershell function [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804):

> ```
> # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> # Script: Get-FileMetaDataReturnObject.ps1 
> # Author: ed wilson, msft 
> # Date: 01/24/2014 12:30:18 
> # Keywords: Metadata, Storage, Files 
> # comments: Uses the Shell.APplication object to get file metadata 
> # Gets all the metadata and returns a custom PSObject 
> # it is a bit slow right now, because I need to check all 266 fields 
> # for each file, and then create a custom object and emit it. 
> # If used, use a variable to store the returned objects before attempting 
> # to do any sorting, filtering, and formatting of the output. 
> # To do a recursive lookup of all metadata on all files, use this type 
> # of syntax to call the function: 
> # Get-FileMetaData -folder (gci e:\music -Recurse -Directory).FullName 
> # note: this MUST point to a folder, and not to a file. 
> # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> Function Get-FileMetaData 
> { 
>  <# 
>   .Synopsis 
>    This function gets file metadata and returns it as a custom PS Object  
>   .Description 
>    This function gets file metadata using the Shell.Application object and 
>    returns a custom PSObject object that can be sorted, filtered or otherwise 
>    manipulated. 
>   .Example 
>    Get-FileMetaData -folder "e:\music" 
>    Gets file metadata for all files in the e:\music directory 
>   .Example 
>    Get-FileMetaData -folder (gci e:\music -Recurse -Directory).FullName 
>    This example uses the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to do a recursive lookup of  
>    all directories in the e:\music folder and then it goes through and gets 
>    all of the file metada for all the files in the directories and in the  
>    subdirectories.   
>   .Example 
>    Get-FileMetaData -folder "c:\fso","E:\music\Big Boi" 
>    Gets file metadata from files in both the c:\fso directory and the 
>    e:\music\big boi directory. 
>   .Example 
>    $meta = Get-FileMetaData -folder "E:\music" 
>    This example gets file metadata from all files in the root of the 
>    e:\music directory and stores the returned custom objects in a $meta  
>    variable for later processing and manipulation. 
>   .Parameter Folder 
>    The folder that is parsed for files  
>   .Notes 
>    NAME:  Get-FileMetaData 
>    AUTHOR: ed wilson, msft 
>    LASTEDIT: 01/24/2014 14:08:24 
>    KEYWORDS: Storage, Files, Metadata 
>    HSG: HSG-2-5-14 
>   .Link 
>     Http://www.ScriptingGuys.com 
> #Requires -Version 2.0 
> #> 
> Param([string[]]$folder) 
> foreach($sFolder in $folder) 
>  { 
>   $a = 0 
>   $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
>   $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder) 
>
>   foreach ($File in $objFolder.items()) 
>    {  
>     $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT 
>      for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++) 
>       {  
>         if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) 
>           { 
>             $hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  = 
>                   $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) } 
>            $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash 
>            $hash.clear()  
>           } #end if 
>       } #end for  
>     $a=0 
>     $FileMetaData 
>    } #end foreach $file 
>  } #end foreach $sfolder 
> } #end Get-FileMetaData
> ```

Then you can try from Powershell:

```
Get-FileMetaData "Parent folder" | where {$_.name -eq "filename"}
```

and filter properties using `Select-Object`.